# I can't update a foreign key and navigation property with entity-framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I am building an application using .net 5 and entity framework core 5.0 with lazy loading. I am trying to update a "Candidato" entity that is a child of a "Puesto" entity.

```
public class Candidato : EntidadBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public int PuestoId { get; set; }

    public string NombrePartido { get; set; }

  
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Puesto Puesto { get; set; }

}

public class Puesto : EntidadBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        public int PeriodoId { get; set; }

        public string Nombre { get; set; }

 
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual Periodo Periodo { get; set; }
}
```

As I only want to make an update of some specific fields, first I obtain the current one from the database, to this I assign the properties that interest me, including the foreign key "PuestoId", and I save this same entity as follows :

```
        Candidato actual = CandidatosDAO.GetCandidato(candidato.Code); //actual.PuestoID = 3 ; actual.Puesto.Code = 3

        actual.PuestoId = candidato.PuestoId; // actual.PuestoId = candidato.PuestoId = 1; actual.Puesto.Code = 3
        actual.NombrePartido = candidato.NombrePartido;

        CandidatosDAO.ActualizarCandidato(actual); //After performing update "actual" returned to actual.PuestoID = 3

public static Candidato GetCandidato(int canCode)
{
    ContextDB db = new ContextDB();

    return db.Candidatos.Where(m => m.Code == canCode).FirstOrDefault();
}

internal static void ActualizarCandidato(Candidato candidato)
{
    candidato.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
    ContextDB db = new ContextDB();

    db.Candidatos.Update(candidato);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

My problem is that when i assign the new "PuestoId" to "actual", the navigation property "Puesto" is displayed with the old one related entity, and after performing "UpdateCandidate", the "PositionID" of "actual" returns to its old value, ignoring updating it.

The only way I found to get it to update correctly was by changing "Candidatos.Update(candidato)" to "db.Entry (candidate) .State = EntityState.Modified", but the related entity "Puesto" is yet in the old one.

Comment: It may not be the real cause for your problem, but I am very suspicious that you are creating `new ContextDB()` object every time you get the objects from Entity Framework. You should get DBContext through dependency injection. Why are your methods static, anyway

Comment: And what does Lazy Loading have to do with your question?

Comment: I've read that DbContext should be short lived and use one per operation, that's why I'm handling it like this. Regarding lazy loading, I note that the db.Candidates.Update method could be updating according to the navigation property loaded by lazy loading, while ignoring the "PuestoID" property

Comment: I suggest you follow some Entity Framework Tutorial and use it as a baseline for your code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0 What are you using `EntidadBase` for?

Comment: EntidadBase give me "CreateDate" "UpdateDate" fields and a method to serialize
  
        public string GetJson()
        {
            string result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, this.GetType());

            return result;
        }

Comment: I advise to avoid inheritance in entity classes. Maybe a extension method `GetJson` would be enough.

Comment: Can you specify that EntityFramework used? EF 6 or EF Core?

Comment: I use EF Core 5